# When the Prometheus crashed, was anyone alive except Shaw and Vickers?

Tags: prometheus

When we first met everyone, it seemed like a large number of people were present but since Janek asked only Vickers and his two pilots if they wanted to leave the ship, it seems implied that every other person was already dead so that when the Prometheus did stop the juggernaut, only Vickers and Shaw were alive (and it turned out David if he counts).

Is that correct?